# $f$ is an entire function, show that $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|a_n|}{n+1} \leq \pi \int_{0}^{2 \pi}|f(e^{i \theta})| \,d\theta. $

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ be an entire
>     function. Show that $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|a_n|}{n+1} \leq \pi
>   \int_{0}^{2 \pi}|f(e^{i \theta})| \,d\theta. $$

The Cauchy integral formula gives
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{f(e^{i \theta})}{e^{i (n+1) \theta}} i e^{i \theta} \, d \theta = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} f(e^{i \theta}) e^{-i n \theta} \, d \theta. $$
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|a_n|}{n+1} 
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1} \left|\int_0^{2 \pi} f(e^{i \theta}) e^{-i n \theta} \, d \theta \right|  \\
&\leq  \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1} \int_0^{2 \pi} \left| f(e^{i \theta}) \right| \left| e^{-i n \theta} \right| \, d \theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1} \int_0^{2 \pi} \left| f(e^{i \theta}) \right| \, d \theta.
\end{aligned}
$$
It seems that this method doesn't work. Is there any idea to estimate it?

Comment: Are you sure that's a $\pi$ out in front of the integral and not a $\frac{1}{\pi}$ or even $\frac{1}{2\pi}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a theorem due to Hardy. See for example:

- Kenneth Hoffman, Banach space of analytic functions, the theorem at page 70
- Peter Duren, Theory of $H^p$ spaces, corollary to theorem 3.15 at page 48